# Setting JAVA_OPTS in open shift is not working

Tags: spring, openshift

I am trying to set java options for my spring application in open shift and its not working. I tried exporting JAVA_OPTIONS and _JAVA_OPTIONS in my app and still I see a file not found exception in my spring initialization exception.

I am trying to load a properties file in spring which is picked based on the environment variable

stack trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config_${targetEnv}.properties]

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the JAVA_OPTS_EXT environment variable to set any extra JAVA_OPTS that you would like your application to use.